# Can't figure out this Error "Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value.'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KO_PYJKHglo) and currently facing some problems. Where it all started is somewhere at 8:56 in the youtube video.

This is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:secondlife_mobile/model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => PlayerModel(), child: const PlayerApp()),
    ),
  );
}

class PlayerApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<PlayerApp> createState() => _PlayerAppState();
}

class _PlayerAppState extends State<PlayerApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController? _controller;
  Animation? _waveAnim;
  Animation? _waveConstAmpAnim;
  late PlayerModel model;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 20))
          ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _waveAnim =
        Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 1).animate(_controller! /*null safe*/);
    _waveConstAmpAnim = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        curve: Curves.easeInSine, parent: _controller! /*null safe*/));
    _controller!.forward(); //null safe 6:32
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    model = Provider.of<PlayerModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 16,
              color: const Color(0xFFd6dde5), //Background Color
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 30.0,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 90,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'Music title',
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'Music artist',
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 75,
                    ),
                    buildRecordPlayer(),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: const <Widget>[
                        Text('time'),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        /*buildWave(width),*/
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        Text('end'),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRecordPlayer() {
    return Container(
      height: 270,
      width: 270,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/vinyl.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            Colors.blue,
            BlendMode.color,
          ),
        ),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/SL.png',
          height: 165,
          width: 165,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my model.dart file

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'musicdata.dart';

class PlayerModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Music> musicList = [];
  int _currentTrack = 0;

  PlayerModel() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.nameList.length; i++) {
      musicList
          .add(Music(artistName: Data.artistList[i], name: Data.nameList[i]));
    }

    musicList.removeWhere(
      (musicItem) => musicItem.name == null || musicItem.artistName == null,
    );

    for (var musicItem in musicList) {
      musicItem.duration = Duration(
        minutes: Random().nextInt(5).clamp(1, 5),
        seconds: Random().nextInt(59),
      );
    }

    for (var music in musicList) {
      print(music.name);
    }
  }

  int get currentTrack => _currentTrack;

  set currentTrack(int currentTrack) {
    _currentTrack = currentTrack;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  resetList() {
    for (var music in musicList) {
      music.isPlaying = false;
    }
  }
}

class Music {
  String? name;
  String? artistName;
  Duration? duration;
  bool? isPlaying = false;
  Music({this.duration, this.artistName, this.isPlaying, this.name});
}
```

When I run this code with 'Run Without Debugging' this shows up.
[image: emulator]

So I started debugging and this showed up.
[image: debug]

And this is how my debug console looks like right now.
[image: debug console 1]
[image: debug console 2]

Comment: next time you should choose some videos near present time :) 2 years ago is too old, it may not suitable now & causes errors :) Just little advice

Comment: This was the only tutorial out there that handles with the UI that I want to create :(

Comment: try to debug, it is list range issue